# Table cells with overflow: hidden and absolutely positioned elements

Tags: html, css

I have this classic `<td>` which has the style attribute `overflow: hidden` set. Inside the cell, I've put a `<div>` with `position: relative`, and inside the block there are absolutely positioned large images that I want to be clipped to the boundaries of the cell. Meaningful example:

```
...
<td style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 50%;" src="verylargeimage.png" />
    </div>
</td>
...
```

It seems to work fine in IE8, IE9, Firefox and Opera, but it fails on Chrome: the image spans over the boundaries of the cell.

I have the same behaviour when I print the page in IE.

I'm aware that the `overflow` attribute on table cells isn't well defined. Is there any way to obtain the desired effect *without* using background images? The result must be printable.

**UPDATE** I don't want to use Javascript either. I want it to be my last resort.

Comment: I would advise you to use `width` and `height` attribute of `<img>` tag for shaping the images inside table-cell. But seems not useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

overflow : hidden has a meaning - which is hide everything which is going out of "defined" area. which means you will need to define what will be your width / height or both will be and it will hide anything which des not fit there.

Comment: You don't have to define the width and the height of every element with `overflow: hidden` to make it clip what's outside its boundaries. And anyway, I can't do that with those cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `table-layout:fixed` on the table element and defined width/height on the `td`. It stops the layout engine from trying to adjust the table cells based on their contents. It's still not gaurenteed to work but it's your best shot. Frankly though I don't think it can really be done.

I should point out that `overflow` on table cells is actually well-defined - the standard specifically doesn't support it. What you're doing is a hack.

Comment: It's a hack, indeed. Too bad I can't put a fixed height to the cells, since they have variable height.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make use of the CSS Clip property and it is not even CSS3. Looks like it fits in your kind of situation.

The clip property is like a mask. It allows you to mask the content of an element in a rectangle shape.

Check this link below and read the CSS Clip part.
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-simple-but-useful-css-properties

Comment: I may use it, but since the height of the cells is variable, I can't really using it. Not without Javascript: I can use it and it would be easy to fix everything, but I'd like to use a pure CSS solution.